# Appium Java Test On BlueStacks 10

Tags: java, appium, adb, emulation, bluestacks

I'm trying to run my appium test on Bluestacks, but it does not runs, not by code not even appium inspector can connect,

here are my desired capcabilities

```
        dc.setCapability("deviceName", "ONEPLUS 10 PRO");
        
        dc.setCapability("udid", "emulator-5554");
        
        dc.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

//      dc.setCapability("androidVersion", "14");
        
        dc.setCapability("appPackage", "com.applisto.appcloner");
        
        dc.setCapability("appActivity", "com.applisto.appcloner.activity.MainActivity");    
        
        dc.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");
        
        //dc.setCapability("noReset",true);
        
        Check();
        
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub") , dc);
```

Android Debug Bridge is enabled in Bluestacks emulator.

here is log

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest appiumtests.appiumtest.setup
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: zipAlignApk failed. Original error: Command 'C:\\Users\\chali\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\build-tools\\33.0.1\\zipalign.exe -f 4 C:\\Users\\chali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-server\\apks\\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk C:\\Users\\chali\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\202384-3480-1esyamz.mmuh\\appium.tmp' exited with code 1. Stdout: ''; Stderr: 'Unable to open 'C:\Users\chali\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk' as zip archive
' 
Host info: host: 'DESKTOP-UO09GDH', ip: '172.20.10.5'
Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision: '040bc5406b'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '19.0.2'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:appActivity=com.applisto.appcloner.activity.MainActivity, appium:appPackage=com.applisto.appcloner, appium:autoGrantPermissions=true, appium:deviceName=ONEPLUS 10 PRO, platformName=ANDROID, appium:udid=localhost:5555}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {appActivity: com.applisto.appcloner.acti..., appPackage: com.applisto.appcloner, autoGrantPermissions: true, deviceName: ONEPLUS 10 PRO, platformName: ANDROID, udid: localhost:5555}}]
Capabilities {appActivity: com.applisto.appcloner.acti..., appPackage: com.applisto.appcloner, autoGrantPermissions: true, deviceName: ONEPLUS 10 PRO, platformName: ANDROID, udid: localhost:5555}
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:140)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:133)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:102)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:182)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:518)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:159)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:89)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:101)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:113)
    at appiumtests.appiumtest.setup(appiumtest.java:53)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:69)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:390)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:325)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.invokeTestConfigurations(TestRunner.java:663)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:652)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:614)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1280)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1200)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1082)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

SKIPPED: appiumtests.appiumtest.testAppCloner
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: zipAlignApk failed. Original error: Command 'C:\\Users\\chali\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\build-tools\\33.0.1\\zipalign.exe -f 4 C:\\Users\\chali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-server\\apks\\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk C:\\Users\\chali\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\202384-3480-1esyamz.mmuh\\appium.tmp' exited with code 1. Stdout: ''; Stderr: 'Unable to open 'C:\Users\chali\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk' as zip archive
' 
Host info: host: 'DESKTOP-UO09GDH', ip: '172.20.10.5'
Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision: '040bc5406b'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '19.0.2'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:appActivity=com.applisto.appcloner.activity.MainActivity, appium:appPackage=com.applisto.appcloner, appium:autoGrantPermissions=true, appium:deviceName=ONEPLUS 10 PRO, platformName=ANDROID, appium:udid=localhost:5555}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {appActivity: com.applisto.appcloner.acti..., appPackage: com.applisto.appcloner, autoGrantPermissions: true, deviceName: ONEPLUS 10 PRO, platformName: ANDROID, udid: localhost:5555}}]
Capabilities {appActivity: com.applisto.appcloner.acti..., appPackage: com.applisto.appcloner, autoGrantPermissions: true, deviceName: ONEPLUS 10 PRO, platformName: ANDROID, udid: localhost:5555}
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:140)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:133)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:102)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:182)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:518)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:159)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:89)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:101)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:113)
    at appiumtests.appiumtest.setup(appiumtest.java:53)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:69)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:390)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:325)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.invokeTestConfigurations(TestRunner.java:663)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:652)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:614)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1280)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1200)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1082)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

I checked adb connect and it's working.
adb devices shows bluestacks but still cannot connect